# How to go fullscreen in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to go fullscreen in Xcode? similarly to VS.net ? 
and if there is, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, the modern answer to this old question has two parts:

1) Use View->Fullscreen to go full screen

and ... so you don't end up with one fullscreen window per file (which would be ridiculous) ...

2a) Use Shift-Option-click to open new files in the same window

2b) Use Navigation Preferences to specify that files always open in a new tab

Answer (score 2):

With Xcode 4.1, a build-in full screen mode in included.

It works pretty well if you don't use multiple monitors.

Comment: good. but i'm still hesitating going for the newer xcodes, very different than the old ones.
but i do use the multiple monitors. what happens?

Comment: Xcode 4 is different, but better IMO. This is what happen when in fullscreen. http://www.macrumors.com/2011/06/15/users-with-multiple-monitors-lions-full-screen-apps-are-not-for-you/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the newest version of Xcode is in an application window, so that would be able to 'go fullscreen'. Are you using the newest version of XCcde? http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html

Comment: No i'm still using Version 3.2.4 (1708)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) plugin [Megazoomer](http://ianhenderson.org/megazoomer.html) for that. That's a plugin that will add a zoom menu item to every Cocoa application which will show the app's content in full screen.

Slight problem though, it doesn't work with Xcode out of the box. Building the old version for 32Bit with GC enabled works when running Xcode 3.2.4 in 32-Bit mode. But unfortunately, Ian did not release the sources for the 64Bit version. So if you really really want it, ask him for the sources and build a version that runs in 64Bit Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't seem there's a decent one

Edit:
This was for XCode 3 and earlier, XCode 4 and later came in one window.
Please refer to other answers

Comment: in the new versions of xcode(with one window) ... i.e. 4+
you can view in fullscreen, and then hide the navigator(left) pane...
same for Debug Area, and Utilities... and that's pretty close to fullscreen