# Xcode 4 fullscreen mode not available

Tags: xcode4

Ok.

Using XCode 4 for a few weeks now. By and large a great improvement.

According to users who answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4334772/830899), Xcode 4 has a full screen mode.

On my system however, here is what I see when I attempt to turn on full screen.

[image]

I am using one monitor, and it's an Apple LED Cinema Display:

[image]

Is there something I am missing?

XCode version :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running Snow Leopard or Lion? I don't think XCode 4.1 supports fullscreen on Snow Leopard because fullscreen apps are a Lion feature.

*EDIT:* In fact yes, your Xcode build number indicates Snow Leopard. Unfortunately, fullscreen mode is not supported. Which makes me wonder why they even bother putting the menu item in there if it's never going to work..

Comment: "why they even bother putting the menu item in there" Subtle hint for you to upgrade ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the shape of your UI buttons, it looks like you're on Snow Leopard 10.6 or earlier.

Lion 10.7 provides a whole new system/API for full-screen, and it's possible that Xcode only supports full-screen on Lion.

Upgrade to Lion :)